# Why do I need to index my data frame to map() after doing map(str_match_all())?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, purrr

I'm trying to parse a data frame containing strings of characters to extract the maximum values (numerically), and having some trouble.

If I start with a tibble like this:

```
tester <- tibble("phyloP46way_primate" = c(".{9}", "0.055{1}0.064{3}", "0.225{1}", "0.271{1}", "-0.706{1}-0.708{1}0.248{3}0.298{3}"))
```

and then use `map()` or `modify()` to apply `str_match_all()` to pick out the values from each character vector, I get back a tibble (for `modify()`) with the 5 observations (each a list of character matricies returned by the 5 calls to `str_match_all()`) (or a list of 1 containing the list of 5 character matrices (for `map()`).

```
regex ≤- "(?:(?:-?\\d+\\.?\\d+?)|\\.)(?=(?:\\{\\d+\\}|;|$))"

> str(foo_tbl<- tester %>% modify(str_match_all, pattern = regex))
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ phyloP46way_primate:List of 5
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "."
  ..$ : chr [1:2, 1] "0.055" "0.064"
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "0.225"
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "0.271"
  ..$ : chr [1:4, 1] "-0.706" "-0.708" "0.248" "0.298"

> str(foo_list<- tester %>% map(str_match_all, pattern = regex))
List of 1
 $ phyloP46way_primate:List of 5
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "."
  ..$ : chr [1:2, 1] "0.055" "0.064"
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "0.225"
  ..$ : chr [1, 1] "0.271"
  ..$ : chr [1:4, 1] "-0.706" "-0.708" "0.248" "0.298"
```

Now, what I *want* to do is apply a function to each one of those “rows”. But when I try to map, it only appears to join them all together in a single vector and just pick the single max from the entire batch, rather than one/row:

```
> map(foo_tbl, function(x) list_to_max(x))
$phyloP46way_primate
$phyloP46way_primate[[1]]
[1] "0.298"
```

unless I do some weird indexing and map over `foo_tbl[[1]]` instead of `foo_tbl`:

```
map(foo_tbl[[1]], function(x) list_to_max(x)) %>% unlist()
[1] "."     "0.064" "0.225" "0.271" "0.298"
```

I think my `list_to_max()` must be doing unexpected things because these behave as I’d expect:

```
> invisible(map(foo_tbl, function(x) print(paste0("x is: ", x))))
[1] "x is: ."                                              
[2] "x is: c(\"0.055\", \"0.064\")"                        
[3] "x is: 0.225"                                          
[4] "x is: 0.271"                                          
[5] "x is: c(\"-0.706\", \"-0.708\", \"0.248\", \"0.298\")"
> invisible(modify(foo_tbl, function(x) print(paste0("x is: ", x))))
[1] "x is: ."                                              
[2] "x is: c(\"0.055\", \"0.064\")"                        
[3] "x is: 0.225"                                          
[4] "x is: 0.271"                                          
[5] "x is: c(\"-0.706\", \"-0.708\", \"0.248\", \"0.298\")"
```

here’s my function:

```
list_to_max <- function(character_vector) {
  numbers <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(character_vector))
  if (all(is.na(numbers))) {
    return(".")
    } else {
      numbers %>% max(., na.rm = TRUE) %>% toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString` will coerce everything into a comma-separated string, which is not very useful. Here's a workflow that keeps everything within the original data.frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tester <- tibble("phyloP46way_primate" = c(".{9}", "0.055{1}0.064{3}", "0.225{1}", "0.271{1}", "-0.706{1}-0.708{1}0.248{3}0.298{3}"))

tester %>% 
    mutate(p_clean = gsub('\\{.*?\\}', ' ', phyloP46way_primate), 
           p_list = strsplit(p_clean, '\\s+'), 
           p_list = map(p_list, as.numeric), 
           p_max = map_dbl(p_list, max))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>                  phyloP46way_primate                    p_clean    p_list p_max
#>                                <chr>                      <chr>    <list> <dbl>
#> 1                               .{9}                         .  <dbl [1]>    NA
#> 2                   0.055{1}0.064{3}               0.055 0.064  <dbl [2]> 0.064
#> 3                           0.225{1}                     0.225  <dbl [1]> 0.225
#> 4                           0.271{1}                     0.271  <dbl [1]> 0.271
#> 5 -0.706{1}-0.708{1}0.248{3}0.298{3} -0.706 -0.708 0.248 0.298  <dbl [4]> 0.298
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is that some fields of my real data include both null values (".") and numbers, e.g. "0.55{1}.{3}". `as.numeric()` converts "." to NA, and `max(c(0.55, NA))` returns NA, not 0.55. So if there's a null value, the mutate workflow ends up with the wrong p_max... I'm iterating on it, but would love more suggestions!

Comment: Firstly, `NULL` and `NA` are different things in R, so it's confusing to talk about "null" values. Realistically, it's much more useful to store your data as `NA` than `NULL` or any string or number you're using to represent missing data. Code-wise, you can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `max`, though it will return `-Inf` when there is only `.`, though that can be converted back to `NA`.